# can someone break this quad formula down for me?

Tags: quadratic-forms, quadratics

[image]

Can someone explain how this person yield the stuff on the right side using quad formula?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! I am sure that people here will help you but will not do your homework. Please explain what you tried and where you are stuck. It is just a quadratic equation.